# PIP uninstall shows package uninstalled, but actually it is not

Tags: pip, openstack

I am trying to remove and install again a package, 'python-keystoneclient' using `pip`. The problem is, when I run `pip uninstall python-keystoneclient`, it is showing successfully uninstalled:

```
root@openstack1:~/cinder# pip uninstall python-keystoneclient
Uninstalling python-keystoneclient:
Proceed (y/n)? y
Successfully uninstalled python-keystoneclient
```

but when I do a `pip search python-keystoneclient`, it shows:

```
root@openstack1:~/cinder# pip search python-keystoneclient
python-keystoneclient     - Client library for OpenStack Identity API
                        (Keystone)
INSTALLED: 0.2.1 (latest)
```

I have tried installing the package again, but it shows `requirement already satisfied`. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are it's installed somewhere else via a package or mechanism that PIP isn't entirely aware of. Plus last I heard, pip uninstall worked in the simple cases, but it was easy to fool and not entirely consistent on all platforms.

I've resorted to doing something like

```
python -c "import sys;import pprint;pprint.pprint(sys.path)"
```

to show me where python is potentially finding it's modules - that will show you if you've done something like left a local directory somewhere in the system path for python (happens to me after doing a "python setup.py develop" from a directory when I'm root and not paying attention).

You can also just ask keystoneclient where it's been imported from with a similar setup, which you can use to find and nuke it:

```
python -c "import keystoneclient;print keystoneclient.__file__"
```

Comment: Great tip! In my situation a package is developed and pushed to Github and published on PyPi. But installing -uninstalling -reinstalling the package made no difference - python always chose an old version. Using this trick revealed that python was consulting  a local copy of the package, a package that was behind the one pushed to github.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually uninstall the keystone-client.

On my server, under
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_keystoneclient-0.3.2-py2.7.egg-info` (you may have a different version number on your server)
you can find a `installed-files.txt` file, which records all the files installed by  keystone-client.

Then, delete them and the related directories in dist-packages.

```
cat installed-files.txt | xargs sudo rm -rf
cd ..
sudo rm -rf keystoneclient python_keystoneclient-0.3.2-py2.7.egg-info
```

Now, keystoneclient has been fully uninstalled.